# electronically activated mechanical release mechanism

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pcb, mechanical

I’m hacking a toy and would like to fire a spring loaded sponge missile.  I’m having trouble googling for some sort of PCB mounted mechanical latch.  Or any type of tiny mechanical mechanism that I can trigger from a microcontroller.  The solenoids that I saw required too much current.  I’m hoping for something with a peak draw of a milliamp or less because this will be running on a watch battery.   Any ideas on how I can achieve this?  I’m open to any type of electronically activated mechanical release mechanism that would release a spring which is compressed by the user (but the latch needs to fit in about a cubic centimeter or less).

Comment: What have you found? A button cell can supply enough juice for a brief pulse of many, many mA if you use it to charge a capacitor.

Comment: Does it has to be a solenoid? What about a small DC motor to release the spring latch? If the motor needs more torque, add some gears to it (or just buy a DC motor with a gearbox).

Answer (score 1):

As one commenter suggested, you are absolutely in the motor domain. Brushed dc and stepper motors come in *very* small packages. The choice of motor depends on the mechanism you built. If you have an old cell phone with vibrator you can try and use that motor.

You would probably need to add a capacitor to handle the current needed to briefly turn on the motor.